Transforming strings into n * n ascii value matrix
I am currently trying to make a c function to transform a string into an n*n matrix made from the ascii value of the characters of the string.For example the string "Wordsss" should give a matrix such as
87  111 82
100 115 115
115 0   0

The space between the differents values should be tabulations.
My current code is :
int matrix_size(int length)
{
    int n = 0;
    double square = sqrt(length);

    if ((int)square % 1 != 0 ){
        n = ((square / 1) - ((int)square % 1)) + 1;
        length = n;
    } else {
        n = square + 1;
        length = n;
    }
}

int key_matrix(int ac, char **av)
{
    int length = strlen(av[2]);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int n = matrix_size(length);
    int limit = pow(n, 2);

    while(i < limit){
        if(i % n == 0 && i != 0){
            printf("%d\n", av[2][i]);
            ++i;
        } else if (i > length && i < limit){
            printf("%d\t", 2);
        } else {
            printf("%d\t", av[2][i]);
            ++i;
      }
   }
}


(int)square % 1 != 0 is always false. All integers are multiples of 1.

It looks like you have a couple of misconceptions about how C functions work. Assigning to length, for instance, has no effect, and you're promising to return int but returning nothing. This invokes undefined behavior.

Use the ceil() function to round up to the next integer.

I thought i had to put the (int) because i was going for an operation between double and int.That's at least what made the compilation impossible on my end.My current code display the ascii values but doesn't use the "\n" at the right moment making my matrix stray from the n * n format.

Alright thx @Barmar i'll look into the ceil function use.

I have successfully implemented the ceil() function. However my main problem still remain as the first line of my matrix still display n + 1 number of values making the last line display n - 1 numbers of values.

Also i would greatly appreciate any website you recommend to correct the misconceptions @Chris talked about.

@Tempest_Sword Curious what is double square ... (square / 1) suppose to do other than result in square with no type change?

"the first line of my matrix still display n + 1 number of values making the last line display n - 1 numbers of values". That is because array indexing starts from 0. av[2][3] is the fourth element.

There are a whole bunch of issues here.

Both of your functions invoke undefined behavior since they promise to return int but do not have a return. In the case of key_matrix it appears the correct return type should be void since this function appears designed only to print output.
As noted by Barmar (int)square % 1 != 0 is always true.
In matrix_size the last action you take is to assign to length, but as length is a local variable (an argument) this has no effect. You may be thinking this will modify the argument passed in, but to do that you'd have to pass a pointer, then assign to that memory location.
You test the length of the third element of av in int length = strlen(av[2]); without checking that the array contains that many strings. Presumably ac contains this information. It's unclear why the third string in the array is important.

If I want to get the size of the output matrix based on the length of the string, I'll find the floor of the square root. If multiplying that my itself yields the original length, it's fine as-is. This covers numbers like 9 or 16. Otherwise, it'll return that number plus one.
This neatly handles cases where floating point math says the square root of something like 10000 is 99.999999... rather than 100.
size_t matrix_dimension(size_t length) {
    size_t s = floor(sqrt((double)length));

    if (s * s == length) {
        return s;
    }
    else {
        return s + 1;
    }   
}

Now, I'll write a function to print a "matrix" for one string. If we need to handle multiples, we can simply write a loop and call this function multiple times.
Note that I use a width specifier on my format specifier to achieve tabulation rather than tabs.
void print_matrix(char *str) {
    size_t slen = strlen(str);
    size_t len = matrix_dimension(slen);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            size_t k = i * len + j;

            if (k >= slen) {
                printf("%4d", 0);
            }
            else {
                printf("%4d", (int)str[k]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


Thank you @Chris.My code now works well.Even though  i got an answer to my question, i remain open to websites to solidify my base skills in c programming.

Just to help with part of OP's code.
int length = strlen(av[2]); matrix_size(length); looks like it is suppose to return the ceiling of the square root of the string length.

Although is is not expected for OP's strings to exceed INT_MAX, the return type of strlen() is size_t, some unsigned type and is the preferable type to use when handing string lengths and sizes.

sqrt() is a floating point function and sometimes returns a value only near a whole number even when a perfect integer square is provided.  In general, avoid floating point functions for integer tasks.  Yet short of writing an integer square root routine, we might as well carefully use sqrt().  **1


Alternative
#include <assert.h>
#include <limit.h>
#include <math.h>

int matrix_size(const char *s) {
  size_t length = strlen(s);

  size_t side = ceil(sqrt(length));
  // With a reasonable quality sqrt() and with OP's sample data,
  // I'd expect this assert to _nearly_ always pass.
  assert(size == 0 || ((side-1)*(side-1) < length);

  assert(side <= INT_MAX);
  return (int) side;
}


**1
Although perhaps beyond OP now, a unsigned uisqrt(unsigned t) (which rounds down) as a basis what should be done with OP's square root of a size_t.
unsigned uisqrt(unsigned t) {
  unsigned s, b;
  for (b = 0, s = t; s; b++, s >>= 1) {
    ;
  }

  s = 1u << (b >> 1);
  if (b & 1) {
    s += s >> 1;
  }

  do {
    b = t / s;
    s = (s + b) >> 1;
  } while (b < s);

  return s;
}


Thank you for taking time to answer @Chris i'll make sure to try the INT_MAX macro a try.
